# Change default language for specific AlertDialog

Tags: android, internationalization

in my android App, i support different languages and the default language is german. All works fine.
For a specific Dialog, i want to change the default language. There will be popup a message and this message default language should be english than german. So, if i switching the language to french and do not have values-fr, they should use english and not german.

I don't know how i can solve that problem. I did not found a solution to check, if that string exists in the french language or not and choose otherwise the english one with code like that:

```
Configuration config = new 
Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration());
config.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
Context localContext = context.createConfigurationContext(config);

localContext.getText(resID).toString();
```

But this will not help me.

An other solution could be, to add the english values to the default-file and translate them in the specific values-de to german and so on. This is not possible in this project by using phraseApp and be compatible with oder platforms like iOS. There u can only mark one language as default and the platform will generate all files for your system.

What i need is a possibility in Code.

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks alot